# Why can't my .sty file be found? I followed the MacTeX instructions

Tags: mac, mactex, texmf, directory

I created a new package as a `.sty` file. I want to be able to use it in all of my documents.

I followed the instructions on the [MacTeX website](http://www.tug.org/mactex/faq/index.html#qm05). I located my `Library` folder in `Macintosh HD` using `Command + Up`. It had a `TeX` folder, but no `texmf` folder, so I created one. In fact, I created the following subdirectory (at least that's what I think it's called) :

`~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`.

I added my file, `mystyle.sty`, to this folder. Then I attempted to compile a minimal document using the command `\usepackage{mystyle}`. I got the error message `File 'mystyle.sty' not found.` What should I do?

Comment: On the folder `latex`, create a subfolder `Mystyle`, and in it add the file `mystyle.sty`.   I'm not sure if you can directly add `mystyle.sty` in the root of the `latex`folder. Does this advice help?

Comment: @quark67 That did not fix the problem I get the same error message.

Comment: @quark67 Now `mystyle.sty` is in the folder `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/Mystyle`

Comment: When I have manually installed a package which was not in TeX live, but available in CTAN, I always do as I previously say, and never had error. Have you tried with your `.sty` file in the same folder as your `.tex` file? Is the compilation correct with `.sty` here?

Comment: @quark67 Yes it works fine then. But I’d prefer not to have to organize things that way if possible.

Comment: I read answers of this question: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/132405), specifically for MacTeX. I don't see your error. Perhaps you could add the tag [mactex] in your question for more visibility.

Comment: @KJO From the MacTeX website linked above: "It is not necessary to run texhash when adding files to this local tree."

Comment: @simplejack agreed texhash not always needed if it is in the correct TDS relative position but should not cause harm as it is done regularily

Comment: @KJO No, it's better not to run `texhash` on the local folder.

Comment: I typed `texhash` in Terminal and clicked `Enter` but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're sure you created the `texmf` folder in `~/Library`, i.e., in the library folder of your home directory, and not `/Library`?  In the Terminal, what does the command `ls ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex` return?

Comment: @AlanMunn ok noted but texhash should only work where its supposed to traverse should it not

Comment: I think so. It is in the same folder as `System` and `Users`. It is in the second highest level after the one with `Macintosh HD`, `Network`, etc.

Comment: No, that's incorrect.  That's the system library. You need to make the folder in the library that is in your home user folder.

Comment: @AlanMunn I moved it and it works now. Thanks a lot, sorry for the confusion. I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Sounds like you are using `/Library`, the Library folder at the root of your HD. You should be using `~/Library`, the Library folder in your HOME folder. That Library folder is normally invisible. To open it in Finder click on th Go menu and hold down the Option key to see a menu item to open that folder.  You can make it permanently visible if you HOME folder but opening that folder, typing Cmd-J, an checking the box about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local `texmf` folder has to be created in your home Library folder, not the system library folder.  You can navigate to that folder from the Finder by using the Go Menu:  (Command-Shift-G) Goto Folder.

[image]

In the dialogue box type `~/Library` (the `~/` is important).

Now you can create the `texmf` folder. For a LaTeX package, it minimally needs to have a folder `tex`, containing a folder `latex`, and optionally a folder for your style file itself (although this is strictly speaking not necessary).